# I am getting an alert bad js fiddle configuration

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am trying to learn react from scratch.
- so I am trying to display hello world.
- but when I run the fiddle **I am getting an alert bad js fiddle configuration**.
- can you guys tell me how to fix it?
- providing code and fiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/q7yvmsa3/1/

```or-tag-here
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Fork base reactjs fiddle they have given. https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara hey buy can't I achieve without forking others...is there any other way ??

Comment: React.createClass is deprecated. Use create-react-app for boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change few JavaScript settings in jsFiddle to make it work.

Click on JavaScript settings icon at the top right corner of the JavaScript window. Select `"JavaScript 1.7"` for **LANGUAGE** and `"No wrap - in <head>"` for **LOAD TYPE**. After that, it should work as expected.

Comment: The alert is coming from https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js file which checks for these two options. Probably,  because it's required to run babel transformation correctly in the browser.

Comment: Ok why we need to change load type